# Dimensional regularization: order of integration

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, regularization, dimensional-regularization

This is a two-loop calculation in dim reg where I seem to be getting different results by integrating it in different orders. I am expanding it about $D=1$. What rule am I breaking?

$$\int \frac{d^{D} p}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^{D}q}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{p^2+4m^2}{(q^2+m^2)((q-p)^2+m^2)}=?$$

---

If we integrate $q$ first, the inner integral converges in $D=1$
$$\int \frac{d^{D}q}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{(q^2+m^2)((q-p)^2+m^2)}=\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{p^2+4m^2}$$
then integrating over $p$, by the rules of dimensional regularization we have
$$\int \frac{d^{D} p}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{m}\frac{p^2+4m^2}{p^2+4m^2}=0.$$

---

If we integrate $p$ first we have
$$\int \frac{d^{D} p}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{p^2+4m^2}{(q-p)^2+m^2}=\int \frac{d^{D} u}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{u^2+2u\cdot q +q^2+4m^2}{u^2+m^2}=\frac{q^2+4m^2}{2m}+\int \frac{d^{D} u}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{u^2}{u^2+m^2}$$
where in the last equality we threw away the $u\cdot q$ term by symmetric integration, and split off the terms in the numerator that converge in $D=1$. The remaining term is a common integral in dim reg (though perhaps the limit $D=1$ is not)
$$\int \frac{d^{D} u}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{u^2}{u^2+m^2}=\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{D/2}}\frac{D}{2}\Gamma(-D/2)(m^2)^{D/2}= -\frac{m^2}{2m}$$
where we used $\Gamma(-1/2)=-2\sqrt{\pi}$.
Now integrating the outer integral over $q$ using the same rules discussed above,
$$\int \frac{d^{D} q}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{2m}\frac{q^2+3m^2}{q^2+m^2}=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$$
What part is invalid?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind the integral you claim evaluates to 0?

Comment: @JCW, In general an integral of a constant like this that would produce a power law divergence like $\Lambda^D$ if we were doing cutoff regularization vanishes. If you split it into separate $p^2$ and $4m^2$ terms and use the rules of dim reg you can also see this.

Comment: Which 2-loop Feynman diagram and which theory (Lagrangian) is this integral from?

Comment: @Qmechanic, It's from the large N perturbation theory of the O(N) sigma model, taken at $D=1$. It's a diagram with two ordinary bosonic propagators and one unusual Lagrange multiplier field propagator which is where the factor in the numerator comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, when you set
$$
\int \frac{d^{D}q}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{(q^2+m^2)((q-p)^2+m^2)}=\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{p^2+4m^2}
$$
the correct answer actually has a $+\mathcal O(d-1)$ piece. The $p$ integral has $1/(d-1)$ divergences which, when multiplied by the missing subleading piece, leaves a finite contribution.

We can do the integrals exactly in $d$. For the $q$ integral we combine denominators à la Feynman, and do the linear shift $q\to q+(1-x)p$. We get
$$
\frac{2 \pi ^{d/2}}{(2 \pi )^d \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}\int_0^\infty\frac{q^{d-1}}{\left(m^2-p^2 (x-1) x+q^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm dq=\frac{2^{-d-1} (2-d) \pi ^{1-\frac{d}{2}} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right) }{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{1}{m^2-p^2 (x-1) x}\right)^{2-\frac{d}{2}}
$$
Next we evaluate the $p$ integral:
\begin{align}
-\frac{2^{-d-1} (d-2) \pi ^{1-\frac{d}{2}} \left(2 \pi ^{d/2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right)\right)}{(2 \pi )^d \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}\int_0^\infty p^{d-1} \left(4 m^2+p^2\right) \left(\frac{1}{m^2-p^2 (x-1) x}\right)^{2-\frac{d}{2}}\,\mathrm dp=\\
=-2^{-2 d-1} d \pi ^{-d} m^{2 d-2} (-((x-1) x))^{-\frac{d}{2}-1} (8 d (x-1) x+d-8 (x-1) x) \Gamma (-d)
\end{align}

Finally, we perform the $x$ integral:
\begin{align}
\frac{2^{-2 d-1} (d-2) \pi ^{1-d} m^{2 d-2} \left(\csc \left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right) \Gamma (-d)\right)}{\Gamma \left(2-\frac{d}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}\int_0^1((1-x) x)^{-\frac{d}{2}-1} (-8 d (1-x) x+d+8 (1-x) x)\,\mathrm dx=\\
\color{red}{\frac{2^{1-2 d} \pi ^{2-d} m^{2 d-2} \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}}
\end{align}

For $d\to 1$ you can expand this as
$$
=\frac12+\big(\log\frac{m}{\pi}+\frac12\gamma\big)(d-1)+O(d-1)^2
$$
where I haven't bothered to include the standard $\mu^\epsilon$ scale to get a dimensionally consistent series.

We correctly reproduce the leading $1/2$ result.

Comment: Hi, I think I might include a brief comment on this integral in a paper, and I'd like to cite your answer. Do you have a real name you would prefer I use? I could post my email here and then delete the comment after you've verified you've seen it if you are worried about privacy

Comment: Hi @octonion, thank you for the consideration, but I value my anonymity too much to do that -- I'd rather not share my true name here, nor by email. You don't have to cite this answer. But if you really want to, you can use "anonymous user" or something like that :-)

Comment: Sure, I understand. I still feel weird about not citing so I'll probably still put in a citation to this webpage. Thanks again!